# Python ascii.read tab(?) delimiters

Tags: python, python-2.7, delimiter

I am trying to use ascii.read to scan in a large number of tabulated data files. The column headings do not appear to have self-consistent delimiters. There is a range from 2 to 7 spaces between each column header. The files looks something like this:

```
  K    WAVELN    NEFF       GEOM ALB   BOND/QFIT  BOND/GEOM  Q-FITTED
   1  0.3000000    0.0556723    0.0000000    0.0000000    2.1435934    2.0582306
[...]
[...]
```

I first suspected I could treat them tabs, however this does not appear to be the case:

```
raw = (ascii.read('filename', delimiter='\t')
```

will read the file but returns only a quite useless single column of data.

Now, this would not be a problem under normal cases - a simple

```
delimter='\s'
```

could have done the trick. However much to my frustration, one column is named "GEOM ALB" - complete with a space in the middle. This fouls up the delimiter, as it thinks this is two column headers, not one:

```
raw = (ascii.read('filename',delimiter='\s')
InconsistentTableError: Number of header columns (8) inconsistent with data columns (7) at data line 0
```

This is solveable by replacing the "GEOM ALB" header with "GEOM_ALB" in the files in question, however I would prefer to avoid spending the time to write the script to do this, particularly if there is a more simple and elegant solution.

Comment: It sounds like you should be using fixed-width columns rather than delimited ones.

Comment: Good idea o11c - I hadn't thought of that. I gave it a whirl and came up with a bad result; the reader failed to read the table correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a workaround for my problem here. By calling ascii.read as

```
raw = (ascii.read('filename',guess=False,header_start=None,data_start=2,names=('K','WAVELN','NEFF','GEOM ALB','BOND/QFIT','BOND/GEOM','Q-FITTED')))
```

I was able to bypass ascii.read's attempts to find and apply header names and define them myself. The key of course being

```
header_start=None
```

which tells ascii.read that there are no headers.